# case statement strip out characters and compare values

Tags: t-sql, case

Below is my case statement.Which is working fine.

```
 WHEN ISNUMERIC(ldd.Value) = 0 
                                    THEN 'NOTHING'
                    WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL,ldd.Value) > 9 
                                    THEN 'HIGH'
                    WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL,ldd.Value) < 7.0 
                                    THEN 'LOW'
                    WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL,ldd.Value) BETWEEN 7.0 AND 9.0 
                                    THEN 'MEDIUM'
                    WHEN ISNULL(ldd.Value,'') = '' 
                                    THEN 'NOTHING'
    END CASE_STATEMENT
```

The coloumn Value has values like

```
Value         CASE_STATEMENT
7.3              MEDIUM
9.2              HIGH
8.4              MEDIUM
9.1%             NOTHING
6.1              LOW
8.0              LOW
5.9%             NOTHING
```

How can i get those % stipped out and make it go to their respective bucket. For eg 9.1% should go in HIGH and 5.9% in LOW. Change the result in

```
 Value         CASE_STATEMENT
    7.3              MEDIUM
    9.2              HIGH
    8.4              MEDIUM
    9.1%             HIGH
    6.1              LOW
    8.0              LOW
    5.9%             LOW
```

Comment: REPLACE( ldd.Value, '%', '') ? But you need to cache it to access in CASE statement to avoid copy paste and performance issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, assuming there is a REPLACE function (SQL Server) or some equivalent in the RDBMS you're using.

```
WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%', '')) = 0 
                                    THEN 'NOTHING'
                    WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL,REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%', '')) > 9 
                                    THEN 'HIGH'
                    WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL,REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%', '')) < 7.0 
                                    THEN 'LOW'
                    WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL,REPLACE(ldd.Value, '%', '')) BETWEEN 7.0 AND 9.0 
                                    THEN 'MEDIUM'
                    WHEN ISNULL(ldd.Value,'') = '' 
                                    THEN 'NOTHING'
    END CASE_STATEMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that is VarChar storage - you have to use `REPLACE` to get the % out and then convert to a numeric type to do range comparisions

```
Select Cast (Replace (Value, '%', '') as Float)
```

For ease of use, I would consider using a derived table

```
Select Value,
    Case when Value = 0 Then 'Nothing' 
     when Value > 9 Then 'HIGH' 
     when Value < 7 Then 'LOW' 
     when Value BETWEEN 7.0 AND 9.0  Then 'MEDIUM' 
    End
From
(
    Select Cast (Replace (Value , '%', '') as Float) as Value
    From
    (
        Select '7.3' as Value
        Union Select '9.2'
        Union Select '8.4'
        Union Select '9.1%'
        Union Select '6.1'
        Union Select '8.0'
        Union Select '5.9%'
        Union Select ''
    ) Value_Raw
) Value_Converted
```